# Twice Continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $A$ be the set of twice continuously  differentiable functions on $\,\left[0,1\right]\,$ and 
$$
B=\left\lbrace \;f\in A \mid \;f\left(0\right)=f\left(1\right)=0,\;\, f'\left(0\right)=2 \,\right\rbrace
$$
Then what is $\;\displaystyle\min_{f\in B}\int_0^1\! \left(\,f''\left(x\right)\right)^2dx$?

I am not able to get anything out of the question except for taking a particular example of $\,f\left(x\right)=2x\left(1-x\right)$.
Please can somebody tell the general thing?

Comment: Since $f(0)=f(1)=0$, there is some $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. Then $\sqrt{\int_0^1 f''^2} \sqrt{\int_0^1 1 }\geq \sqrt{\int_0^c f''^2} \sqrt{\int_0^c 1}\geq \left|\int_0^c f''\right|=2$. I don't know if this lower bound is achieved...

Comment: Similarly, the stronger inequality holds: $\sqrt{\int_0^1 f''^2}\geq 4 + |f'(1)|^2$.

Comment: How you got this stronger inequality Sir?